# Can convolution be generalized to 2D from several 1D convolutions?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a function $\mu(x)$ that I need to convolve with several functions $\nu_n(x)$. I'm currently taking the DFT of $\mu$ and multiplying it individually with the N DFTs of the functions $\nu_n$ and then taking the inverse DFT to obtain the convolution.

Can I instead define
$m(x, y) = \mu(x), n(x, y) = \nu_y(x)$ for discrete $y$, take the 2D DFT to obtain $M(u, v)$ and $N(u, v)$, which I then multiply element wise as $C(u, v) = M(u, v) N(u, v)$ and then take the inverse 2D DFT to obtain the same result $c(x, y)$ as I did elementwise in the above method?

Comment: Sure. Convolution is separable: http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/288

Comment: Remember to use zero padding when you compute the DFTs.